# Let $\beta=(1,3,5,7,9,8,6)(2,4,10)$. Find smallest positive integer n for which $\beta ^{n} = \beta ^{-5}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $\beta=(1,3,5,7,9,8,6)(2,4,10)$. Find smallest positive integer n
>   for which $\beta ^{n} = \beta ^{-5}$

$|\beta|=21 \Rightarrow \beta ^{21} = (1) \Rightarrow \beta ^{16} = \beta ^{-5}$

Hence $n = 16$ is required answer.

Is this correct ?

Comment: What is $\beta\,$? A permutation of $S_{10}$?

Comment: Your calculation is correct.

Comment: @Bernard most probably yes. But nothing was mentioned in my book. Also I think it won't make any difference if it was member of $S_{n}$ $n \geq 10$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct but you could add some details:

$\beta ^{n} = \beta ^{-5}$ iff the order of $\beta$ divides $n+5$.

The smallest positive $n$ such that $21$ divides $n+5$ is indeed $16$.